# Ubuntu 12.04 stereo duplex sound problem

Tags: pulseaudio

Ubuntu 12.04; linux-kernel 3.2.0-27; alsa driver ver. 1.0.24
i have some problem with my HDA Intel ALC662 rev1. When i unmuting front mic in alsamixer, noise appear in my speakers in rear panel, but anyone devices is not plugged in in front panel. Besides in pulseaudio-control panel in hardware properties my device set to analog stereo duplex, and i can't set it to analog stereo output beacouse it's always set back to stereo duplex.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the soundcard profile was limited in gnome-control-center for a simpler user experience (see [bug #972554](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/972554)). This also affects the switching to `Analog stereo` from `Analog duplex stereo`. We can still do this with [**pavucontrol**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/pavucontrol) [image: Install pavucontrol]. This may also improve the noise you are experiencing when no device is plugged in the input jack.

From the log files attached to [bug #1027570](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1027570/) we can see that we try to switch to the microphone port but fail. We may disable the automatic switching by commenting out the following line in `/etc/pulse/default.pa` to look like this:

```
# load-module module-switch-on-port-available
```

This requires editing this file as root (e.g. by running `gksu gedit /etc/pulse/default.pa`). To take effect we need to restart pulseaudio with

```
 pulseaudio -k
```

If that does not help please remove the `#` again to re-enable switching audio to a new audio port when it becomes available.

Comment: there is another problem: when i plug the mic on the front panel, the settings of pulseaudio in input options, is shown attached to the front of the mic,but when I plug headphones to the front panel, mic in the input option begins to blink rapidly as if it connects and disconnects

Comment: Try to see if you get any pulseaudio errors from running a [pulseaudio log](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio/Log). You may also add any relevant errors to your question.

Comment: [Bug #1027570 with a pulseaudio log added](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1027570/)

Comment: Looks like there is an issue with your front mic jack detection - it seems to constantly switch from unplugged to plugged and back. Unfortunately I have no good idea why that is - smells of a hardware issue (try to refix cables to your front panel?).

Comment: i tested the front panel in M$ Evil 7, there's works fine... but i'll rechecked my hardware. Thanks any way)

Comment: @user78104: it may be an issue with module switch-on-port-available - see edit.